# how router handles 'well known' ports from host

Tags: sockets, routes

Very short qustion. Lets say user1 is connected to internet and running a http server @ local. he needs to set port forwarding to work this. redirecting all incoming requests from public ip to local ip's port 80.

my doubt is that, User1 opens mozilla firefox , lets say, port 12343 , assigned by the os.
from this, (192.168.0.14:12343) to google.com:80... sometimes our router changes the incoming port to another port @ NAT . clear..
 My question: is there is any port forwarding set at the router to handle to route the packet.. ie, requests from google:80 to :12343  . plz correct me if am wrong  at any protocol suite layers. i am new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When connection is established through NAT, NAT maintains mapping between inside port and outside port. That is, when the packet comes from outside to the port 54321, NAT knows to forwward it to internal network IP 192.168.0.1., port 12345.

To explain further, let's dwell into details. Let's talk about transparent NAT. Transparent NAT's are ones which do not require any special configuration on locla software (unlike HTTP proxy servers, for instance). They usually serve as network gateways, so that OS knows to route network trafic to such a gateway (almost all home routers work in this mode).

When someone opens web page from desktop - local address 192.169.1.1, local port 12345, remote address stackoverflow.com, remote port 80 - OS directs trafic to network gateway (192.168.1.0).

Gateway sees the trafic as coming from 192.168.1.1, port 12345. On the packet, it replaces 192.168.1.1 with it's outside IP (say, 2.2.2.2) and gives it a port - say, 54321. It also creates an entry in it's mapping tables, indicating that all trafic incoming from outside for port 54321 is to be forwarded to 192.168.1.1, port 12345. StackOverflow server sees the trafic as coming from gateway, and responds back to the gateway address and port. Gatewat sees response, consults mapping table and forwards it to the local machine, where it is seen by the browser - and thus my answer is displayed on your screen.

Comment: can u plz make it some more clear.. ie, NAT contains a database of ports which are currently pushed or invoked and only accepts connection<destination port> from ports which it has in it's database. Isn't???

Comment: No, why? Did I misunderstand the question? NAT has no idea of well-known ports.

Comment: no.. i got a small spark here.. if possible , explain this line. NAT maintains mapping between inside port and outside port., y 54321 reversed to 12345

Comment: Edited answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing to do with NAT here. NAT just translates the internal local address(like 192.168.1.1) to an external global address(like 139.130.4.5). I hope you have adequate knowledge on OSI model. Let me explain it. When a packet reaches the transport layer,it is assigned a random port number(ranging from 0-65535),either TCP or UDP, by the OS. However, the OS can only port numbers from 49152 to 65535, as several ports are registered or is used for some specific process. A port is used to identify a service or a process. After adding port number, the packets are given to the network layer, which adds the source address and destination address of the packet. Switching is a process that happens in the network layer. This switching mechanism is responsible for the source to destination delivery of packets. Internet uses packet switching. When you are sending a packet in this switching mechanism, the packets get routed to several switches between the source and destination. Every packet that is sent through these switches are routed based on a switching table or routing table. This table contains details such as the MAC address and a physical port of the switch through which the packet is received and sent.
This is the only port forwading that happens inside a router or a switch. Delivering the packet to a specified MAC address is the only duty of a switch.

Every packet you sent through a router goes to its destination based on the routing table. Several protocols work in this layer to make the source to destination delivery possible and some of them are ARP,IP,RARP etc.

Additionally, a packet is encapsulated with information from top layers as it moves down the layers. So, at the receiver side, the packet will comes at network layer and then gets decapsulated and it is moved to the transport layer, which then decapsulate the packed and send it to the corresponding process base on the port.

So, what I told is that there is no connection with a process (port number) and the physical port of the router. It is true that the packet travels through the physical port of the router but it doesn't know anything about the process that sends the packet.